# How make my component take all available space with Tailwind?

Tags: css, angular, tailwind-css, angular-router

I use Tailwind CSS to style an Angular app. Structure is simple: `app.component.html` to display a navigation bar and a footer, and components are displayed in the remaining available space with `overflow-y`.

Problem: my component is not taking all the available remaining space using `w-full` or `flex-grow`.

app.component.html:

```html
<div class="flex flex-col h-screen w-screen">
  <app-topbar></app-topbar>
    <div class="flex flex-grow overflow-y-auto mx-6 mt-6 bg-red-700">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  <app-footer/>
</div>
```

collection.component.html

```html
<div class="flex h-full w-full bg-amber-400">
  <form [formGroup]="searchForm" *ngIf="(currentBreakpoint$ | async) === Breakpoints.XSmall">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput placeholder="" [value]="searchForm.value.name" formControlName="name">
    </mat-form-field>
  </form>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="search()" [disabled]="searchForm.invalid">Rechercher</button>
</div>
```

Here, the yellow part represents `collection.component.html` and it should take all the available width. If this is because the parent width is not defined, I don't know how to do it as I can't access the tag `<collection.component />`.

[image]

EDIT: if I use w-[calc(100vw-48px)] (100% of view width minus some of margins) instead of w-full, it works, but I want to avoid this kind of calculation as margin will change with media queries

Answer (score 1):

You have the following code wrapping your app's `router-outlet` and it is `flex`. It should also have `w-full` and it'll fix your issue.

**Instead of:**

```
<div class="flex flex-grow overflow-y-auto mx-6 mt-6 bg-red-700">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>   
</div>
```

**Do this:**

```
<div class="flex flex-grow overflow-y-auto mx-6 mt-6 bg-red-700 w-full">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>   
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried but it does not solves the problem